# About proofs by contrapositive and proofs by contradiction

Tags: logic, proof-writing, proof-theory

I'm a little confused about the difference between these two types of proof. As I have been taught them, it seems like proofs by contrapositive are just a subset of proofs by contradiction.

Say we want to prove $P \implies Q$. Here is how I've been taught to use both proofs:

**Contrapositive:** We assume $\lnot Q$ and from this we try to conclude $\lnot P$.

**Contradiction:** We assume $P$ and $\lnot Q$ and from this we try to deduce a contradiction.

My question is, let say we proved  $P \implies Q$ by contrapositive, so we proved  $\lnot Q \implies \lnot P$. Wouldn't this be equivalent to assuming $P$ and $\lnot Q$ and then use $\lnot Q$ to prove $\lnot P$, so we would deduce the contradiction $P \land \lnot P$?

Comment: They're very similar. When contraposition works, a proof by contradiction feels unneccesarily clunky (you've just added a few lines to the top and bottom for me to read and process with no actual value), while some times a proof by contradiction (or, equivalently, by contraposition and then splitting into the two cases $P$ and $\lnot P$) is necessary.

Comment: @Arthur sorry for wasting your time sir. Feel free to edit the question so no one else has to process useless information.

Comment: I'm sorry. That's not what I meant. Your question is fine. I meant that when you _make such a proof_ (i.e. a proof by contradiction which is basically a proof by contraposition with an added assumption of $P$ at the top), there are lines in that proof with no value. Specifically, the lines "assume $P$" at the top of the proof and "Thus $P$ and $\lnot P$, which is a contradiction" at the bottom.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using proof by contradiction vs proof of the contrapositive](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/262828/using-proof-by-contradiction-vs-proof-of-the-contrapositive)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The two approaches are not equivalent, even if they are quite similar and related. More precisely, proofs by contrapositive are a *proper* subset of proofs by contradiction.

Every proof by contraposition can be reformulated as a proof by contradiction, as you correctly noticed. Indeed, suppose you have a proof $\pi$ of $\lnot Q \implies \lnot P$; then you can prove $P \implies Q$ by contradiction, by assuming $P$ and $\lnot Q$, which yields a proof of $\lnot P$ (via *modus ponens* between the assumption $\lnot Q$ and the conclusion $\lnot Q \implies \lnot P$ of $\pi$) and then you get the contradiction $P \land \lnot P$.

But not every proof by contradiction can be reformulated as a proof by contraposition, as well explained in the accepted answer of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/262828/288417). Indeed, proofs by contradiction are "more general" (i.e. they can be applied to a wider set of propositions to prove) because you can stop when you find *any* contradiction, not only a contradiction directly involving the hypotheses. More precisely, in a proof by contradiction of $P \implies Q$, we assume $P$ and $\lnot Q$ and we deduce a contradiction $R \land \lnot R$; in the particular case where $R = P$ then (usually) you can reformulate your proof as a proof by contraposition, otherwise you cannot.

---

*Remark.* Both proofs by contraposition and proofs by contradiction are valid in classical logic, but in general they are not valid in intuitionistic logic (roughly speaking, a constructive logic that does not admit the excluded middle law). For a more detailed analysis of the validity of these kinds of proofs, see for instance [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/838184/288417).

Comment: oh, that's an eye opener, thanks!